# Vaadin - Align icon on button

Tags: button, icons, alignment, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm working on a simple back/forward-navigation with Vaadin existing of two buttons, each with a label and an icon (arrows left and right).

```
navigator = getUI().getNavigator();
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(backViewID)) {
        backButton = new Button(backButtonI18n, IconCache.FAST_REWIND_BUTTON.getIconResource());
        backButton.addClickListener(getBackButtonListener());
    }

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(nextViewID)) {
        nextButton = new Button(nextButtonI18n, IconCache.FAST_FORWARD_BUTTON.getIconResource());
        nextButton.addClickListener(getNextButtonListener());
    }
```

How can I align the icons on each button? Currently it looks like
"<< Back" ">> Next", because icons are aligned on the left and text is aligned on the right side. I now want to align the icon for the next-button on the right side and the text on the left, to make it look like "<< Back" "Next >>".

I hope someone can help me with that.

Cheers, Hendrik

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Valo, this is relatively easy. You just need to add a style name which is already shipped with the theme `forwardButton.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_ICON_ALIGN_RIGHT)`:

```java
public class ButtonsComponent extends HorizontalLayout {
    public ButtonsComponent() {
        Button backButton = new Button("Back", FontAwesome.ARROW_LEFT);
        Button forwardButton = new Button("Forward", FontAwesome.ARROW_RIGHT);
        forwardButton.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_ICON_ALIGN_RIGHT);
        addComponent(backButton);
        addComponent(forwardButton);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can just copy the same exact CSS from the [`valo-button-icon-align-right-style`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/WebContent/VAADIN/themes/valo/components/_button.scss) into your theme, and add that particular style to your button: `forwardButton.addStyleName("my-custom-button-with-right-alligned-icon");`

```
.my-custom-button-with-right-alligned-icon {
  [class*="wrap"] {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .v-icon {
    float: right;
    $padding-width: ceil($v-unit-size/2.4);
    margin-left: $padding-width + ceil($padding-width/-5);

    + span:not(:empty) {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Either way, you should end up with something similar to:

[image: sample]